# change association from one to many to many to many

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, many-to-many

I have two models lets suppose

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
end
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belogns_to :a
end
```

now because of some system changes I need to convert this association to many to many some thing like this

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bs
end
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :as
end
```

OR

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cs
  has_many :bs, through: :cs
end
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cs
  has_many :as, through: :cs
end
class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :b
end
```

what is best way to do this and most importantly I DO NOT WANT TO LOSE MY EXISTING DATA. Existing records should automatically adopt these changes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

many to many means you have connected table(model) between two other, so you could just create this one and write relation to it, after that you could remove garbage ids from B.

A, B are not good names;)

imagine you have User and Comments, and you decide that comments can have also many users, so it can look like:

```
class User
  has_many :comments # will be changed

  has_many :user_comments
end

class UserComments
  belong_to :user
  belong_to :comment
end

class Comment
  belong_to :user # id will be removed from table and relation will be changed

  has_many :user_comments
end

# as direction for import could be something like:

User.all.each do |user|
  user.comments.each do |comment|
    UserComments.create user: user, comment: comment
  end
end
```

Comment: by this i can lose my records I want that if b record belongs to a a record then it should become b.as=[a] does it make sense?.

Comment: why you should lose data? you will create new relation `UserComments` which connect `User` to `Comment` and just then remove `user_id` field from `Comment` table. Until `user_id` exist for comments, your old relations are valid

Comment: `sql` variant you could look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554357/how-to-migrate-existing-records-to-match-new-orm-in-rails