# how to migrate existing records to match new ORM in rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Recently I changed the model relationships in an app I am building. Because these changes will be later deployed I need to know how to migrate existing data to the new structure. This feels like a scary prospect.

my original set up was like this..

1. a client has many locations
2. a location belongs to a client

I then created a join table so that a `client has many locations through client_locations`.

So from the old data structure I have client_id in the locations database. How would one set about moving this data to the new structure?

Comment: this question looks about the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25492415/change-association-from-one-to-many-to-many-to-many

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migrating the data itself could be done with just SQL. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO client_locations (client_id, location_id)
SELECT client_id, id FROM locations;
```

Then clean up the locations table if you need to with:

```
ALTER TABLE locations DROP client_id;
```

unless you need to maintain an owner of the location in addition to the many to many relationship.